# Parallelizing for-loops in Python using joblib & SLURM

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, slurm, joblib

I have a list of 100 tuples `tuplelist` that serve as inputs to an external function. The external function returns a value, and that value is appended to an array, like so (`MainFile.py`):

```
from ExternalPythonFile import ExternalFunction

valuelist = []
for a,b in tuplelist:
    value = ExternalFunction(a,b)
    # more functions here
    valuelist.append(value)
print(len(valuelist))
```

The output for `print(len(valuelist))` when using the for-loop above is `(100,)`.

Now since the order of the tuples and how they are appended do not matter in my case,  I wanted to parallelize the for-loop since it would take ~10 min to process 100 tuples, and I'm expecting to scale that number. I have tried  a joblib implementation below (`MainFileJoblib.py`):

```
from ExternalPythonFile import ExternalFunction
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
import multiprocessing

valuelist = []

def TupleFunction(a,b):
        value = ExternalFunction(a,b)
        # more functions here
        valuelist.append(value)

with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
    Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(TupleFunction)(a,b) for a,b in tuplelist)

print(len(valuelist))
```

I'm running all of this on a unix compute cluster, but the runtime was still similar at ~8 min. The output was also wrong, it printed `(0,)`.

Looking at `htop` I found that there were in fact 10 cores being used but each core only at 20% usage.

I also have tried to run the joblib implementation via SLURM:

```
srun --ntasks=1 --ncpus-per-task=10 python3 MainFileJoblib.py
```

which was definitely faster at around ~2 min, but again it gave the wrong result `(0,)`.

What's the best way to parallelize the original for-loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joblib manages by itself the creation and population of the output list, so the code can be easily fixed with:

```python
from ExternalPythonFile import ExternalFunction
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
import multiprocessing


with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
    valuelist = Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(ExternalFunction)(a, b) for a, b in tuplelist)

print(len(valuelist))
```

If for some reason you need to update an array-like object, you could make use of numpy memmap, as per the following minimal example:

```python
import tempfile
import numpy as np
from ExternalPythonFile import ExternalFunction
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
import multiprocessing


# define function to update your array
def fill_array(mm_file, i, tuple_val):
    a, b = tuple_val
    value = ExternalFunction(a, b)
    # more functions here
    mm_file[i] = value

# create a temporary folder
tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
# create a file where to dump your array
values_fname_memmap = Path(tmp_dir).joinpath("values_memmap")
values_memmap = np.memmap(values_fname_memmap.as_posix(),
                          dtype=np.float,
                          shape=(len(tuplelist), ),
                          mode='w+')

with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
    Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(fill_array)(values_memmap, i, ab) 
                        for i, ab in enumerate(tuplelist))

print(len(values_memmap))
```

If you need to apply a set of transformations to the value (*# more functions*) just make a wrapper around ExternalFunction that outputs the desired value for a given tuple (a, b).

I hope that despite the late response it may still be useful to you.